# Find the number of ways to choose a countable subset of R

Tags: combinatorics, set-theory

I need to find how many ways there are to choose countable subset from $\mathbb R$ the set of real numbers.
This confuse me because $\mathbb R$ is uncountable, although he has countable subsets like Netural Numbers set.

Comment: I do not understand what do you exactly ask, what are the restrinctions of these sets?

Comment: @ÀlexRodríguez the only restriction there is that the subset must be countable, and I need to find how many ways there are to choose countable subset of R.

Comment: You can do it in infinitely many ways. Just choose $\mathbb{N}$ and remove a element of it

Comment: "*Infinitely many*" may not be specific enough.  The cardinality of the set of countable subsets of $\Bbb R$ is at least that of $\Bbb R$ if not more... clearly it is at least that of $\Bbb R$ itself since for each $x\in \Bbb R$ you have $\{x\}$ is a countable subset of $\Bbb R$.  It remains to show whether the cardinality is strictly more than $\Bbb R$ or not.

Comment: @Hayden it can be relevant for any subset size? (It seems that's only relevant for specific subset size)

Comment: @JMoravitz How I show that the cardinality of subset is strictly more than R (or not)?

Comment: It is at least the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ and no more than the cardinality of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$.  Since these are the same cardinality ...

Comment: I think the cardinality, almost by definition would be $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$. The question is, is that cardinality equal or larger than $|\mathbb R|=2^{\mathbb N}$.  It's too early and I haven't had my coffee and I'm afraid if I type anymore I'll make a statement that is obviously wrong.

Comment: @fleablood - I think not quite by definition, since several different sequences of reals give the same countable subset  of reals

Answer (score -1):

The cardinality is $\mathfrak{c}$. To show this it suffices to find an injective map from the set of infinite sequences of subsets of $\mathbb N$ to subsets of $\mathbb N$. Consider the map

$$ (A_1, A_2, \cdots ) \mapsto \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \{p_n^{a} : a \in A_n \}$$

where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime.

Comment: how that's connected to number of ways to choose a countable subset from R?

Comment: $\mathbb R$ has the same cardinality as the subsets of $\mathbb N$ and the cardinality of infinite subsequences of subsets of $\mathbb N$ is at least as large as countable subsets of  subsets of $\mathbb N$ (because a sequence is a countable subset with order).

Comment: I'm confused. $\mathfrak{c} > \aleph_{0}$ and we cant write the elements of the set of infinite sequences of subsets of N in order, can we.  And if we can that means $\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \{p_n^{a} : a \in A_n \}$ is countable (which it is) $\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \{p_n^{a} : a \in A_n \}\subsetneq\{$ countable subsets of $\mathbb R\}$. Injective functions into *subsets* prove cardinality is less or equal.  Not more or equal...

Comment: Yes, what I was showing was that the cardinality of countable subsets of $\mathbb R $ is less than or equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb R$. The other direction, that the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ is less than or equal to the cardinality of countable subsets of $\mathbb R$ is obvious, so the two cardinalities are equal.